Проблема с импортом JSTL ClassNotFoundException
Вот ошибка
Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.all_002demployees_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:578)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:422)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:377)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:325)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1431)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1167)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
зависимости pom.xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

это файл jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>All Employees list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>All employees list</h2>
<br><br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${allEmps}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${item.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${item.surname}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${item.department}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>

если убрать цикл и ссылку то все работает корректно пробовал загрузить jstl.jar в папку lib не помогло
